# How can i do custom date picker in react-native

Tags: react-native, datepicker, custom-datetimepicker

**I had used date time picker in react native, but I want to do in my custom UI for the date picker. How can I do it?**

**I want to do as shown in below image in both android and IOS**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Follow the below steps.

1. Use **new Dat**e API to get **Date**, **Month** and **Years** store them in array.
2. then display in **row** so three are side to each other.
3. Hide **Top** and **Bottom** Portion View Using **overflow hidden**

That is it you can generate a Date Picker like you side.

Comment: This answer would be improved with some sample code. Please read [answer].

Answer (score -2):

You can get that look by using the [react-native-date-picker](https://github.com/henninghall/react-native-date-picker) library and the following code:

```
<DatePicker
  date={date}
  onDateChange={setDate}
  mode="date"
/>
```